# Query to retrieve values form DB on multiple criteria

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I Need to retrieve values from database to plot them in graph. For that I need to get values on criteria basis. Data matching different criteria has to be returned as different rows/ column to my query

(i.e)

I have a table called TABLEA which has a column TIME. I need to get the value based on time critreia as a result, count of rows which are matching TIME>1 and TIME<10 as a result, TIME>11 and TIME <20 as a  result and so on. Is it possible to get the values in a single query. I use Mysql with JDBC.

I should plot all the counts in a graph

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(case when `time` between 2 and 9 then 1 else 0 end) as count_1,
       sum(case when `time` between 12 and 19 then 1 else 0 end) as count_2
from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with CASE statements, but they can get kind of verbose. You may just want to rely on Boolean (true/false) logic:

```
SELECT
    SUM(TIME BETWEEN 1 AND 10) as `1 to 10`,
    SUM(TIME BETWEEN 11 and 20) as `11 to 20`,
    SUM(TIME BETWEEN 21 and 30) as `21 to 30`
FROM
    TABLEA
```

The phrase `TIME BETWEEN 1 AND 10) will either return`TRUE`or`FALSE`for each record.`TRUE`being equivalent to`1`and`FALSE`being equivalent to`0`, we then only need sum the results and give our new field a name.

I also made the assumption that you wanted records where `1 <= TIME <= 10` instead of `1 < TIME < 10` which you stated since, as stated, it would drop values where the TIME was 1,10,20, etc. If that was your intended result, then you can just adjust the `TIME BETWEEN 1 AND 10` to be `TIME BETWEEN 2 AND 9` instead.